# SQL filter results based on user/role combination

Tags: sql-server

Given the following tables, I need to filter the *things* data based on which user is making the call as well as additional (optional) filters that consist of a user_id/role combination.

At any time a user should only receive results for things that they are linked to unless they have full access. The additional filters are *AND* filters meaning that the results should satisfy all the filters.

The parameters @user_id, @has_full_access and user_id/role filters are passed through using Dapper.

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id int NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_users PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id)
)

CREATE TABLE user_roles
(
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    role varchar(10) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT FK_user_roles_users FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
)

CREATE TABLE things
(
    id int NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_things PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id)
)

CREATE TABLE thing_permissions
(
    thing_id int NOT NULL,
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    role varchar(10) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT FK_thing_permissions_things FOREIGN KEY(thing_id) REFERENCES things(id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_thing_permissions_users FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
)

INSERT INTO users VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO users VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO users VALUES (4)
INSERT INTO users VALUES (5)

INSERT INTO user_roles VALUES (1, 'Admin')
INSERT INTO user_roles VALUES (2, 'Creator')
INSERT INTO user_roles VALUES (2, 'Owner')
INSERT INTO user_roles VALUES (3, 'Creator')
INSERT INTO user_roles VALUES (3, 'Owner')
INSERT INTO user_roles VALUES (4, 'Creator')
INSERT INTO user_roles VALUES (5, 'Owner')

INSERT INTO things VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO things VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO things VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO things VALUES (4)
INSERT INTO things VALUES (5)

INSERT INTO thing_permissions VALUES (1, 2, 'Creator')
INSERT INTO thing_permissions VALUES (1, 3, 'Creator')
INSERT INTO thing_permissions VALUES (1, 2, 'Owner')
INSERT INTO thing_permissions VALUES (2, 2, 'Creator')
INSERT INTO thing_permissions VALUES (2, 5, 'Owner')
INSERT INTO thing_permissions VALUES (3, 4, 'Creator')
INSERT INTO thing_permissions VALUES (3, 3, 'Owner')
INSERT INTO thing_permissions VALUES (3, 5, 'Owner')
INSERT INTO thing_permissions VALUES (4, 3, 'Creator')
INSERT INTO thing_permissions VALUES (4, 5, 'Owner')
INSERT INTO thing_permissions VALUES (5, 2, 'Creator')
```

The following are some examples of various input combinations as well as the expected results.

```
--Scenario 1:
--Expected Results: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
DECLARE @user_id int = 1
DECLARE @has_full_access bit = 1
DECLARE @filters TABLE (user_id int, [role] varchar(10))

--Scenario 2:
--Expected Results: 1, 2, 5
DECLARE @user_id int = 2
DECLARE @has_full_access bit = 0
DECLARE @filters TABLE (user_id int, [role] varchar(10))

--Scenario 3:
--Expected Results: 1
DECLARE @user_id int = 1
DECLARE @has_full_access bit = 1
DECLARE @filters TABLE (user_id int, [role] varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @filters VALUES (2, 'Creator')
INSERT INTO @filters VALUES (2, 'Owner')

--Scenario 4:
--Expected Results: 3
DECLARE @user_id int = 1
DECLARE @has_full_access bit = 1
DECLARE @filters TABLE (user_id int, [role] varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @filters VALUES (3, 'Owner')
INSERT INTO @filters VALUES (5, 'Owner')

--Scenario 5:
--Expected Results: 1
DECLARE @user_id int = 2
DECLARE @has_full_access bit = 0
DECLARE @filters TABLE (user_id int, [role] varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @filters VALUES (3, 'Creator')

--Scenario 6: 
--Expected Results: no results
DECLARE @user_id int = 1
DECLARE @has_full_access bit = 1
DECLARE @filters TABLE (user_id int, [role] varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @filters VALUES (2, 'Creator')
INSERT INTO @filters VALUES (4, 'Creator')
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/49043) is a SQL Fiddle with the setup.

At the moment, I have the following function that returns all the *things* as well as the role(s) in which the user is linked.

```
FUNCTION GetMyThings (@user_id INT, @has_full_access BIT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT t.id, 'Admin' AS role
    FROM things t
    WHERE @has_full_access = 1

    UNION

    SELECT t.id, tp.role
    FROM things t
        INNER JOIN thing_permissions tp ON tp.thing_id = t.id
    WHERE tp.user_id = @user_id
)
```

I use this function to get a list of *things* that the calling user has access to as well as those for each user in the filters. Finally I return the results that are in both these data sets.

```
DECLARE @my_things TABLE (id INT) 
INSERT INTO @my_things SELECT id FROM GetMyThings(@user_id, @has_full_access)

DECLARE @filtered_things TABLE (id INT) 
INSERT INTO @filtered_things SELECT ft.id FROM @filters f CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT id, role FROM GetMyThings(f.user_id, 0)) ft WHERE ft.role = f.role GROUP BY ft.id HAVING COUNT(ft.id) >= (SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM @filters)

DECLARE @has_filter BIT = (SELECT has_filter = CASE WHEN (COUNT(user_id) > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM @filters)
DECLARE @final_things TABLE (id INT) 
INSERT INTO @final_things SELECT id FROM @my_things WHERE @has_filter = 0 OR id IN (SELECT id FROM @filtered_things)

SELECT * FROM @final_things
```

Is there a better way of doing this? My solution works but with bigger data sets it seems as if the function slows the query down when compared to selecting from the original data.

I've also tried using views but because I need the @has_full_access parameter and separate SELECTs UNIONed together I cannot add a WHERE to each SELECT.